# Подскажите средство наподобие sqlpackage.exe (msbild как пользоватся?)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Я больше за советом, на новой работе дали исследовательскую задачу, после такого долгого карантина не могу нормально поглощать информацию, прошу направить.

В visual studio в средстве SSDT есть средство сравнения двух дакпаков или дакпака и проекта, вроде как msbuild compare, его работа из интерфейса меня устраивает полностью, нужна заставить так же работать из консоли.

Мне нужно чтобы оно работало из командной строки, что бы я там мог гибко настроить его (т.е. например указав конкретный объекты (не типы объектов)), а на выходе получить SQL скрипт обновления.
Если есть хорошие статьи про это прошу скинуть. С английским на ВЫ, но главное чтобы статья была прикольная с примерами.

Sqlpackage не подходит, по необъяснимым мне причинам, но вроде как он какие-то объекты игнорирует или наоборот не может игнорить.
Я пытался поднять какую то инфу по этому поводу, где-то видел что советовали какой-то другой exe из набора visual studio Pro.
Но в принципе подойдет любая штука соответствующая требованиям (даже если платная):

1. Обязательно работа из консоли, что бы все это можно было поставить на поток и не делать руками.
2. Может генерировать SQL скрипт для обновления(желательно конечно, но если умеет только обновлять, тоже рассмотрю)
3. Можно гибко настроить объекты для обновления(ну например разница между дакпаком и проектом(или другим дакпаком) огромная, но я хочу сгенерить скрипт на 3 определенные таблицы и на 2 хранимки(конкретных))
4. Не sqlpackage(хотя интересные статьи бы я рассмотрел, возможно "заказчики" не ведают чего хотят, хотя вряд ли)

Но хотелось бы остаться в рамках visual studio.

Можете рекомендовать даже книги, но хотелось бы какие нить статьи.

Comment: dacfx не подходит? В чем смысл msbuild в рамках dacpac пакетов?